# Error Conversion from type 'InternalField' to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: .net

There is a combobox named as cboEndUser. when i am selecling the item in combobox then this function is called. cboEndUser is filled with by

```
cboEndUser.Items.Add(New itemData(oRec.Fields("FullName").Value, oRec("ContactID")))
```

Item data is a class.

```
Public Class itemData
Public _item As String
Public _itemData As Object

Public Sub New(ByVal item As String, ByVal data As Object)
    _item = item
    _itemData = data
End Sub

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return _item
 End Function
End Class


Private Sub cboEndUser_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cboEndUser.SelectedIndexChanged

            If cboEndUser.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
                PopulateSerialNumberArray(CInt(txtCustomerID.Text), (cboEndUser.SelectedItem)._itemData)
            End If

End Sub
```

Getting the error in the line  PopulateSerialNumberArray(CInt(txtCustomerID.Text), (cboEndUser.SelectedItem)._itemData) . errow is Conversion from type 'InternalField' to type 'String' is not valid.

```
Public Sub PopulateSerialNumberArray(ByRef plCustomerID As Integer, ByRef plContactID As String)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs a string as second parameter.
`(cboEndUser.SelectedItem)._itemData` isn't.

Either change the signature of the function or change the parameter to a string.

Comment: Yes. I changed the second parameter as  (cboEndUser.SelectedItem)._itemData.ToString. Thanks